# Turbo Pascal Homework Problem: Why did Error 57 pop up in a row it shouldn't have?

Tags: turbo-pascal

I attend 1st grade of Highschool. Recently I had an assignment to do in Turbo Pascal and this happened:

```
var
   a,b,x,y,n:integer;
begin
   readln(a,b,x,y);
   if a<b and x<y then n:=a+y;
   if a<b and x>y then n:=a+y;
   if a>b and x<y then n:=b+x;
   if a>b and x>y then n:=b+x;
   writeln(n);
end.
```

An Error 57 appeared in the second if row between "y" and "<".

Can someone explain why this happened?

Comment: Wild guess: the pascal `and` [binds mores strongly than](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_operators.htm) `<`. Add parentheses around the `something<something` clauses.

Comment: Also, please don't post code as images. (not searchable, assistive technologies, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

A web source indicates that `Error 57` is `"Then" Expected` and because you did not surround your `If` comparisons with parenthesis brackets the compiler expects that the next word should be a `then`. Even if the error is not what the source said you still need to enclose your `If` comparisons with parenthesis brackets if you have more than one comparison in one `if`

```
if (a<b) and (x<y) then n:=a+y;
```

Otherwise the compiler thinks you want the comparison to be

```
a < b and x
```

Which will check if `a` is smaller than the result of `b` "ANDed" with `x`